# Class been cache even     cache_class = false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I configured my development.rb to not cache_class, but why it still cache and and didn't update when I make my changes such as adding a binding.pry and puts unless I ctrl+c and rails s again.

I mostly do my development in class EditorHub::ArticlesController, maybe it is because of namespaces?

Any idea why it happens?

```
rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server


#development.rb
CMS::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
end

#application.rb

config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Answer (score 1):

More details on the exact changes you made might be helpful, but in general, changes are made to Classes that are in your models folder should be reloaded on every request and your approach is correct. And changes to many other folders are in your load path so they'll also be reloaded, but not all. You can fix that by changing your load path, but that may be more work than simple ctrl-c and restarting.

I don't think this would work but you could put this in the class not reloading..

```
Rails.application.eager_load!
```

The issue is, you can definitely get the class to reload in development. The I generally find the effort to do so is not worth benefit.

Comment: I mostly do my development in class EditorHub::ArticlesController, maybe it is because of namespaces?

Comment: onfig.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)

Comment: The namespaces might not be automatically loaded. I updated my answer with eager load.